# Simple jquery ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I only need send and receive data between jquery and php file, but doesn't work.

Jquery code:

```
var parametros = {
            "url" : url
    };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: parametros,
    url: 'file.php',

    success: function(data) {
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Php file:

```
<?php 
$other = "other";
$resultado['url'] = $_POST['url']; 
$resultado['other'] = $other;

echo json_encode($resultado);

?>
```

I try to delete  "var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);" line, and work fine, is here my issue?

In this case, the alert(data) contain all the php file, with php tags.

Comment: since you got the php code in your response, then the php code didn't execute, and your webserver sent it out as plain text. You'll have to figure out why (e.g. it's in a .html file, not .php).

Comment: the php script was not activated, instead you just got the file. this probably means that your host is not configured to activate the php, so this request is being treated like any other file request (same as .html files for example). the exception from parseJSON is thrown since you dont pass onto it a valid json string, you are passind php script instead

Comment: I thing that if because execute this code in chrome extension, but how I can extract the vars? parseJSON don't work in this code. This code is correct? the jquery code is js file.